# Statistics collection engine for C++ systems

Tags: design, c++, object-oriented, statistics

We have a research project with idea->prototype->statistics development cycle.
Anyway, our final product is a prototype, so the statistics collection suite is
not used persistently. Supposing I have following class:

```
class Transform {
    private:
        someData;

    public:
        transformForward (inp_block, outp_block);
        transformBackward (inp_block, outp_block);
};
```

Imagine that it is a part of a big system. I need to periodically collect some statistics on such transform (internal data could be considered as well). It seems that adding statistical routines would be a violation of single-responsibility principle. The second smell is that I do not want to touch code that uses `Transform` instances to explicitly invoke these routines. I would be best if I could just
trigger some kind of switch so that the statistics for that module will be collected.

I've met that challenge a number of times and I have a feeling that I'm constantly reinventing the wheel. Is there some good practices for configuring and collecting the statistics suite for a compound system without interfering into it's internal code base?

### UPDATE:

As I can see from the answers proposed, my question is too non-specific, so I'll provide more concrete example.

Consider an image-compression system composed by two *huge* blocks: `Predictor` and `Encoder`. There are a lot of various prediction and compression algorithms, during our research we need to explore the behavior of the components under various conditions. We should answer questions like "how many times the pixel is processed within each context", "how well does this predictor works", "how does each predictor affects the `Encoder`'s internal state" and many others.

Anyway, our final product is just a *Codec* with no statistical suite shipped with it; all kind of statistics collection is used internally during our research. Thus the question arises: how could one build flexible statistics engine that knows the very internals of the system? How could one keep the system itself independent of the statistics engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) pattern might be a good fit here. The `Transform` class defines a set of events that might be of interest to the statistics engine, and the statistics engine registers itself with the relevant `Transform` instance to gather the statistics on that transformation (or the statistics that include that transformation).

**Update**

As stated in a comment, the basic problem is how does the statistics engine know that something of interest has happened. 
You could execute the codec in a virtual machine to keep track of everything (valgrind uses this approach to check memory access), but then you have the problem of deciding what it means that the codec accessed address `0x12345678`.

All other methods of statistics gathering invade into the code-base of the codec in one way or another. The least invasive is probably to add copious amounts of logging and to let the statistics engine analyse that. All logging packages also provide means to disable the generation of the logs with minimal cost, sometimes even compiling those statements to no-ops.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think that Observer could be indeed a great solution, but there is a problem with that approach: the whole system must know that it's publishing some kind of events to the statistical engine. Events could be sent from the deepest corners of every class, so imagine the amount of work required to remove/modify the statistics engine' interface. The whole question is actually about the possible ways of _decoupling_ the working system from the statistical engine.

Comment: @ownclo: The basic problem is that the statistics engine needs some kind of trigger to know that something of interest has happened. Can you update your question to explain what kind of statistics you need to gather? Perhaps some external instrumentation can help you.

Comment: I updated my question and tried to provide more details upon the purposes of such an engine. The problem is that ideally the engine should know the code base, not the code base should depend upon the engine.

Comment: @ownclo: See my updated answer.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion. The system _has_ to send the data to the statistics engine explicitly. I will organize some kind of logger/observer system. In these terms both your and @rwong's answers can be helpful. I hoped that there exist a silver bullet, but it doesn't. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If the internal state of the transform implementation is not considered, [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) seems to be the answer. Otherwise, see [Bart van Ingen Schenau](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/197534/620)'s answer.

Before that could happen, two refactorings are needed on the *existing* code base:

- Create an interface for the methods of the `Transform` classes. This is [Abstraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(computer_science)).
- Existing code that uses the Transform classes must allow higher-level code to specify which `TransformInterface` implementation to be used. This is [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

A decorator class responsible for capturing statistics from the data that pass into and out of the `Transform` interface would:

- Implement the `Transform` interface
- Decorate (wrap-around) a concrete implementation of `Transform`
- Have `transformForward` and `transformBackward` methods which gathers the data, and then forward the call to the concrete implementation.

```
class TransformInterface
{
public: 

    virtual ~TransformInterface() = 0;
    virtual void transformForward ( ... ) = 0;
    virtual void transformBackward ( ... ) = 0;
};

class TransformStatisticsGatherer : public TransformInterface
{ 
public:
    TransformStatisticsGatherer( TransformInterface * pConcreteTransform )
    {
        myConcreteTransform = pConcreteTransform;
    }
    void transformForward ( void* inputBlock, void* outputBlock )
    {
        ... // do something with inputBlock and outputBlock _before_ the call
        myConcreteTransform -> transformForward ( inputBlock, outputBlock );
        ... // do something with inputBlock and outputBlock after_ the call
    }
    void transformBackward ( void* inputBlock, void* outputBlock )
    {
        ... // do something with inputBlock and outputBlock _before_ the call
        myConcreteTransform -> transformBackward ( inputBlock, outputBlock );
        ... // do something with inputBlock and outputBlock _after_ the call
    }
    void getStatistics ( ... )
    {
        ... // return the gathered statistics
    }
private:
    TransformInterface* myConcreteTransform;
    ... // additional private fields for statistics gathering
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, I see a serious disadvantage of this approach: I'll need to change higher-level code every time I want to switch from normal transform to statistical one. Statistics collection is not their responsibility. I'd rather use some kind of publisher/subscriber approach, but I cannot imagine a system where `Transform` do not explicitly send some messages to the statistics engine.

Comment: "Ill need to change the higher level code everytime..." not if you use a factory to supply the Transform, then in the factory method you can use conditional compilation to choose which Transform type to return. Then you an easily switch stats on/off at build time.